# How to remove a menu from gtk_menu?

Tags: menu, gtk

Googled a lot, and tried `devhelp` , there's only one function available `gtk_menu_item_set_submenu ()` , but it doesn't solve my problem.

```
Main Menu->
       Item A-> Sub
       Item B-> Sub
       ...
       Item N-> Sub
       -------------
       Item X
       Item Y
```

I needed to remove "Item A-N" and rebuild them , what i tried so far , is to use `g_free (main_menu)` , causing the whole application to crash.

N is clearly known to me , is there any function to remove first `N` submenu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `GtkMenu` inherits from `GtkContainer`, so any of the `GtkContainer` methods also work on the menu. Use [`gtk_container_remove`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.24/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-remove)`(menu, submenu)`